# Sorting a list by a incremental field based off a group

Tags: list

I have a list that I am wanting to sort.  It is sorting by a facility number facility 1, facility 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12...20,21,22 and so on.  The problem is that SharePoint is showing it as 1,10,11,12..2,21,22,23.  I have a Sorter column that I created to give a the number 1, b the number 2 and so on.  It works on a normal view, but then I incorporated a group to it.  I have two groups, one for complexity, then by Facility.  Inside the facility are certain service areas.  This is where it ignores the sort column and it lists it back to the beginning way.  It shows Complexity 1, facility 1, complexity 1, facility 10...

Please help.

Comment: I found the answer. I had to remove the second group and then order by to get it to work.